# Load data file in MySQL is not working

Tags: mysql, csv

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with my mysql load data infile query?
When I try to run the query below, mysql executes it but it does not import any data. But I don't get any error message as well.

```
load data infile 'data/country.csv' into table country2 
CHARACTER SET utf8 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(LKZ, abbr2, abbr3, code, name, localName) set id=NULL;
```

My database table is

```
CREATE TABLE `country2` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`LKZ` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`abbr2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`abbr3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`localName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The csv im trying to import is http://user.ffuf.de/johngarcia/public/country.csv

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try to remove `set id=NULL;`

Comment: Hi Jens, I tried, it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: working now... I just replaced the '\n' with '\r'        zzzzzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the lines in your CSV file are terminated by `'\r'` ([`carriage return`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return#Computers)), the line ending used by Mac OS before version 10. Change the line:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
```

and it will work.

Comment: Hi Axiac, Thanks for answering. Before I mark your answer as correct, can you tell me how did you know the correct termination keyword?

Comment: I opened your CSV file in [`TextWranggler`](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (I work on a Mac, on Windows you can use [`PSPad`](http://www.pspad.com/) or [`Notepad++`](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) and the line ending is displayed in the status bar. Mac OS used `'\r'` until version 9. They switched to `'\n'` on OSX. Unix-like systems always used `'\n'` while Windows (unfortunatelly still) uses a `'\r'` followed by a `'\n'` to end the lines of their text files.

Comment: '\r'` and `'\n'` are the notations for [`ASCII`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) `CR` and `LF` characters in the [`C` programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) since the 70s. They were adopted by many other languages since then; [`C++`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B), [`PHP`](http://www.php.net), [`Javascript`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) are some of the most used languages nowadays that inherited them.

Comment: Somewhere in the middle of the documentation page for [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) there is the list of special characters recognized by `MySQL` in the `FIELDS ESCAPED BY`, `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` and `LINES TERMINATED BY` clauses.